# divs won't float, can anybody see why?

Tags: css, css-float

I have the following code on the page www.7hermanosmx.com/menu.php - everything is working correctly except the yellow boxes (class menuholder) should be floating left against each other three per row. They steadfastly refuse to do this! I know I have done something wrong, and I know I am going to look silly, but can anybody please help me spot my error?

I have the css...

```
.menutop {
font-size: 18px;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #099;
clear: both;
height: 32px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-top: 5px;
}
.menuholder {
background-color: #FFC;
width: 250px;
height:auto;
float:left;
font-size:14px;
}
.menutext {
font-style: italic;
color: #666;
}
```

and I have the html (delivering database driven content)

```
<div data-binding-id="repeat1" data-binding-repeat="{{FULL_MENU.data.groupBy( &quot;TYPE&quot; )}}" style="width:100%">
<div class="menutop">{{$name}}</div>
 <div class="menuholder"> <div style="padding:8px">
 <div data-binding-id="repeat2" data-binding-repeat="{{$value}}">
<strong>{{NAME}}</strong> 
<font style="font-style: italic; color: #004000;">({{COST.currency( "$", ".", ",", 2 )}})</font><div data-binding-html="{{DESCRIPTION}}" class="menutext"></div>
<br />
</div></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Class `menutop` has `clear: both` which ends floating elements. Put this element into `.menuholder`. http://jsfiddle.net/6jLye800/

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. the css "menutop" is a div after the floats that starts the new line (as well as adds the title of the section) and when I took it out the whole thinkg did start floating, but way out of order.

Comment: Does [this bin](http://jsbin.com/fewili/1/edit?css,output) solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Rafael, thank you so much. It is not quite what I am looking for. The blue title box (first one says ACP) should be 100% width, then the items underneath should be floating with a yellow background. Hope that makes sense and I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)**

**CSS**

```
.fl {
display: table-cell;
width: 276px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
```

Please follow this
**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)** link for demo. Thanks